# Make multidimensional array one dimensional without a foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried the array_reduce and array_merge methods but they don't seem to do what I expected. Is there a way of doing this without a foreach?

I need to convert an array such as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
        )

)
```

Into:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$flat = array_map(function($el) {  return $el['id']; }, $arr);
```

Not this is for php 5.3. If you are using 5.2 youll have to define a function or use [`create_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) instead of passing in an anonymous like i have here.

Comment: this works, do you know of a way of doing this without explicitly stating the id as a key name? For example, I'd like to use this function for results that may have something different than id.

Comment: If you will only ever have one element in the array you could use `array_pop` or `array_shift` to grab that element instead of using the key. Or you could use @rambocoder solution

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5 >= 5.5.0 or PHP 7, I think a much better solution to this problem would be using `array_column`, since it was made for exactly this purpose:

```php
$multidimensionalArray = [
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'somethingElse' => 'foo'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'somethingElse' => 'bar'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'somethingElse' => 'baz'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'somethingElse' => 'bam'
    ],
];

$justTheIds = array_column($multidimensionalArray, 'id');

var_dump($justTheIds);

/*
  array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(4)
  [3]=>
  int(5)
}
*/
```